# displaying an iterator to a vector

Tags: c++, vector, cout

I am working on a project where I am placing an enum into a vector. and I was wondering how I could get functionality like such out of the vector.

```
for(int ii = 0; ii < thing.getSize(); ii++){
    cout << "thing(" << ii << ") = " << toString(thing[ii]) << endl;
}
```

I've tried about 5 different ways to do this, and none of them seem to work. I have read through MSDN vector (vector::end() seemed the most helpful until it said that the operator<< wouldn't accept ii as an iterator.

can somebody help me out? the closest I think I got was

```
vector<int>::iterator ii;
for(ii = things.begin(); ii != things.end(); ii++){                       //764
    cout << "thing(" << (int)ii << "): " << toString(things[ii]) << endl; //765
}
```

but this throws errors that either don't make sense or I can't figure out how to solve.

```
1>c:\...\Project.cpp(764): error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>c:\...\Project.cpp(765): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>c:\...\Project.cpp(765): error C2679: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: What type is `things`? also, the value of each step in the loop will be in `*ii`.  `ii` points to the current location in the vector.  If you need to show the loop counter, you need another variable for that (another int which you can increment alongside `ii` in the `for` loop.

Comment: thing is an enum which I have written a `toString(thing)` for which works (tested). and I will try the separate counter

Comment: An iterator is not an index, it's more like pointer. `thing[ii]` is totally wrong, use `*ii`. Printing out an iterator makes no sense, it has no useful information for the end-user, just like a pointer. Line 764 is OK, I have no idea why your compiler complains. Try to come up with a 10 line program that demonstrates the same error.

Comment: if you wish to iterate `things` with a `vector < int >::iterator`, `things` has to be declared as: `vector < int > things`.

Comment: @Yaniro this solved it. write an answer, and I will +1, and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`things` has to be declared as:

```
vector < int > things;
```

You can enter your values into the vector like so:

```
things.push_back( 1 );
things.push_back( 2 );
```

Then you iterate like this:

```
for ( vector < int >::iterator i = things.begin(); i != things.end(); ++i )
{
    cout << "things( " << ( i - things.begin() ) << " ): " << toString( *i ) << endl; 
}
```

Comment: alternatively if you are using a different type like an enum you would state `vector<TYPE> things;`, and then when the iterator is declared it would be `vector<TYPE>::iterator`

Answer (score 4):

The correct generic way to do this is

```
for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator ii=things.begin(); 
         ii != things.end(); ++ii)
{            
    std::cout << "thing(" 
              << std::distance(things.begin(), ii) 
              << "): " << *ii << std::endl;
}
```

is by dereferencing the iterator and using std::distance to get the distance from the beginning.

further more it is generally considered bad to import an entire namespace it is better to either have explicit using statements or a preferably prefix types with it's namespace.

It is also generally preferrable to use the prefix increment operator for iterators.

Also unless you are doing some interesting formatting there is no need to apply 'toString' to an int. As it has a stream operator defined for it.

Comment: i am not doing a toString() on an int I am doing it on the enum then entire point to the question

Comment: on the statement about including an entire namespace it depends on the compiler some compilers will actively look for all the needed classes/members in the namespace and only include those, and then other will include everything. not to mention that for the most part namespaces are light weight in most cases, and the only time it is truly bad to include an entire namespace is when you are using multiple namespaces the either share names, or members

Comment: No the standard dictates which using namespace does not the compiler. Using namespace is the same as merge the current namespace with the imported on, if the current is the global namespace then you have gone and negated to the benefit of naemspacing in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
cout << "thing(" << (ii - things.begin()) << "): " << toString(*ii) << endl;
```

Comment: ok it did work after changing the type of the vector iterator. ignore last

Answer (score 2):

Iterators behave pretty much like pointers: they indicate the position of the value and you need to dereference them to get the value:

```
std::cout << *ii;
```